# How to put 2 context_object_name for listView Django

Tags: python, django

I have developed a context within a context.

here's my views.py:

```
class AgentClientListView(OrganizerAndLoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "agents/agent_client_list.html"
    context_object_name = "clients"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Client.objects.filter(agent_id=self.kwargs['pk'], agent__isnull=False).order_by('company_name')
        return queryset
```

however I need to add another context_object_name: "agent"

what would I do?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ovveride get_context_data:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(AgentClientListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['agents'] = <Your agent query>
    return context
```